# Opening Units in C++ Builder 10 starts with .h

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle, c++builder-5

About half a year ago our company switched from C++ Builder 5 to the C++ Builder 10 Seattle. If you opened a unit in C++ Builder 5 (via the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) it automatically opened the .cpp file.

Now if you open a unit with C++ Builder 10, it starts with the .h file and I have to switch manually to the .cpp file. This sounds like a minor inconvenience, but it's really annoying that I have to switch every time I open a unit.

Is there a setting that allows me to switch to the old behaviour?

Comment: Reproduced.  I can see how that would get annoying after awhile.  Feel free to file a bug report with Embarcadero at [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I can't reproduce this with C++ Builder 10 Seattle Update 1.